# Copy from Gitlab CI/CD to AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, continuous-integration

I am using Gitlab CI/CD. CI just builds my npm project and I got `dist` folder ready to copy to AWS EC2.

I couldn't find any code which `ssh` to AWS EC2 and then copies my dist folder from Gitlab CI/CD to EC2's specific directory.

Answer (score 0):

There are some other ways of delivering artifacts to an EC2 box besides SSH.

But here's one of the first articles I found on gitlab CI + SSH: https://medium.com/hackernoon/configuring-gitlab-ci-yml-150a98e9765d